# how to find the geometric multiplicity - Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I know what is the algebric multiplicity but I didn't understand what is and how to find the geomtric one.
I've search for an answer but still don't get it. How can I calculate this kind of dim?

Comment: I will assume you are asking about the geometric multiplicity of a number $c$ as an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$. The geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the nullspace of $A-cI$. Do you know how to compute the dimension of the nullspace of a matrix?

Comment: @GerryMyerson - I'm not sure. Can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: Explain how to compute the dimension of the nullspace of a matrix? Sure, you just use elementary row operations to bring the matrix to row-echelon form; then the dimension of the nullspace is the number of columns minus the number of nonzero rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenspace for$~\lambda$ of a linear operator $T$ is $\ker(T-\lambda I)$. It can be found (in coordinates for a given basis) as the solution space of the homogeneous linear system of equations $A_\lambda\cdot x=0$, where the column vector $x$ represents the unknowns, and the coefficient matrix $A_\lambda$ is the matrix of $T-\lambda I$ with respect to the basis. The system will be degenerate (allow more than just the zero solution) if and only if $\lambda$ is actually an eigenvalue of$~T$. By definition the geometric multiplicity of$~\lambda$ as eigenvalue of$~T$ is the dimension of this eigenspace; it is the number of non-pivot unknowns of the system (and also the number of zero rows in its row echelon form).

Comment: Sir, thanks, but I know the definitions but I just don't know what do practicly. I mean, can you explain it with an example with numbers? after geting the characteristic polynomial of the matrix what I need to do for finding the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: You don't need the characteristic polynomial to find the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$; note that my answer does not mention the characteristic polynomial at all. The characteristic polynomial can be helpful in finding the eigenvalue(s) $\lambda$ in the first place (although it is not absolutely necessary; the minimal polynomial will do quite as well for instance). Once you have $\lambda$, you can forget the characteristic polynomial and just solve the system.

Comment: I see no point in generating a specific example; just let $A$ be your favourite square matrix, let $\lambda$ be one of its eigenvalues; write down the matrix $A_\lambda=A-\lambda I$ and the system $A_\lambda\cdot x=0$, and solve it. You can do that better than I can, and it is more instructive.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324427/how-to-find-the-multiplicity-of-eigenvalues - can you just explain why the geomretic mul. of the matrix C is 2?

Comment: There is no such thing as the geometric multiplicity of a matrix; it is the geometric multiplicity _of a given eigenvalue_ for that matrix. The example has two eigenvalues, both with geometric multiplicity$~1$. The geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is never higher than the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$, and if $\lambda$ is indeed a root of the characteristic polynomial$~\chi$, the geometric multiplicity is at least$~1$; for simple roots of$~\chi$ the geometric multiplicity has no choice but to be$~1$. Example settled. Interesting example needs $\lambda$ to be _multiple_ root of$~\chi$.

Comment: Sir, what I still don't get, that both matrices, B & C, and even their characteristic polynomial, their λ eigenvalues and the algebric mult. are the same. What cause the difference that in the first case there's geo. mult. of 2 and in the second case there's a geo. mult. of 1? I just can't see it...

Comment: I suppose you are referring to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/324437/18880). There both matrices have only $\lambda=5$ as eigenvalue; moreover the matrices that I called $A_\lambda=A-\lambda I$ are respectively $B_5=(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix})$ and $C_5=(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix})$. The difference is that while the systems $B_5\cdot x=0$ and $C_5\cdot x=0$ are both degenerate, the first one is more degenerate than the second: $B_5\cdot x=0$ has _every_ $x$ as solution (2 parameters) while the solution of $C_5\cdot x=0$ has only one parameter