# characteristic polynomial of the matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A=$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 &0\\ 0 & -1 & -5\\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{pmatrix} $$
p(x) = x(x+1)(x-2)

Therefore:
x=0, -1 ,2

Now, every eigenvalue is once so the algebric mult. is 1.
But what should I so in order to find the geometric mult.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and you have $3$ distinct eigen values, therefore the algebraic multiplicity for each eigen value will be the same as geometric multiplicity.

Comment: If I had nxn matrix and n eigenvalues then also the geometric mult. and the algebric mult. will be the same?

Comment: as long as you have $n$ "distinct" eigen values then yes.

Comment: what do you mean by "distinct"? different and without x?

Comment: unequal i.e. no eigen values is repeated.

Comment: ok, and what if I have nxm matrix? or if i have nxn matrix but m eigenvalues?

Comment: First of all eigen values are only defined for square matrix. Please pick up a good book on Linear Algebra to further study the topic and clear the doubts.

Comment: Oh indeed, my mistake. but still, when the number of eigenvalues is different then n (when nxn matrix) what should I do?

Comment: @user2969278 You should still pick up a good book on linear algebra and use your own brain finally.

Comment: I know the definitions but I have some problems calculate it preacticlly. I've searched enough and still don't get it. I need someone to show me...

Comment: @AnuragA http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324427/how-to-find-the-multiplicity-of-eigenvalues - can u just explain why the geomretic mul. of the matrix C is 2?