# Help finding the geometric multiplicities of some matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given the matrices to find the geometric multiplicities. I still do not gather the concept. Here is what I have so far:

> $A = \begin{bmatrix}
>  -5&6  &-1 \\ 
>  -5&5  &-2 \\ 
>  4&-6  &0 
> \end{bmatrix}$.

The eigenvalues are $\lambda =-1$ with algebraic multiplicity $2$ and $\lambda = 2$ with algebraic multiplicity $1$. For $\lambda = -1$, we have
$$A + I = \begin{bmatrix}
 -4&6  &-1 \\ 
 -5&6  &-2 \\ 
 4&-6  &1 
\end{bmatrix},$$ 
which can be reduced to get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0 &1 \\ 
 0&1  &\frac{1}{2} \\ 
 0&0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Does this means that  the nullspace is $$\alpha \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
\frac{1}{2}\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \alpha \in \mathbb{C},$$
so the geometric multiplicity is $1$? Similarly, for $\lambda = 2$, we have
$$A -2 I = \begin{bmatrix}
 -7&6  &-1 \\ 
 -5&3  &-2 \\ 
 4&-6  &-2 
\end{bmatrix},$$
which can be reduced to get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0 &1 \\ 
 0&1  &1 \\ 
 0&0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Does this means that  the nullspace is $$\alpha \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \alpha \in \mathbb{C},$$
so the geometric multiplicity is $1$?

> $B = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 &2  &-3 \\ 
>  1&0  &3 \\ 
>  1&-2  &5 
> \end{bmatrix}$.

The eigenvalue is $\lambda = 2$ with algebraic multiplicity $3$. Now,
$$B - 2I = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 &2  &-3 \\ 
 1&-2  &3 \\ 
 1&-2  &3 
\end{bmatrix},$$
which can be reduced to
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 &2  &-3 \\ 
0&0  &0 \\ 
 0&0 &0
\end{bmatrix},$$
 does this mean that the nullspace is 
$$\alpha \begin{bmatrix}
-2\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} + \beta \begin{bmatrix}
-3\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C},$$

so the geometric multiplicity is $2$?

Comment: For clarification read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324427/how-to-find-the-multiplicity-of-eigenvalues/324437) on MSE. Your title asks on *geometric* multiplicity. You speak of algebraic multiplicity the whole time.

Comment: When you compute the dimensions of the various nullspaces, you’re finding the *geometric* multiplicity of those eigenvalues. The algebraic multiplicity is how many times that eigenvalue occurs as a root of the characteristic equation. Other than that, it all looks good to me.

Comment: I had some mistakes, I modified the part when I ask if the geometric multiplicity is correct. I had before 'algebraic' instead of 'geometric'.