# Similar matrices have same Eigenvalues, Is converse true?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that two similar matrices have the same eigenvalues. Is the Converse true? Justify your claim.

I am good with the first part.

I stuck with converse part.

Please help me with the example.

Comment: We would need to control the [multiplicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324427/how-to-find-the-multiplicity-of-eigenvalues/324437) of their eigenvalues, as well as the eigenvalues.  This turns out to be more complicated than might appear at first, because of the distinction between algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity.  Indeed we can have two **dissimilar** matrices, each with only one eigenvalue (say zero) they share, and with the algebraic and geometric multiplicities for that eigenvalue in agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Find two $2\times2$ matrices who both have $(1-\lambda)^2$ as their characteristic polynomial, and therefore have the same eigenvalues. See if you can make one diagonalizable (actually, diagonal), the other not. Then the two would not be similar, since conjugating the diagonal one would leave it unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must have not just the same eigenvalues, but the same associated eigenvectors. Consider  $ I_2:= 2\times 2$ identity and $I_2'$ with exactly one  $1$ ( or any non-zero number) in any of the non-diagonal entries.

Comment: Even this is not enough in higher dimensions. This question is related to Jordan normal form.

Comment: @Bernard: Do you mean we may have similar matrices even when same eigenvalues have different associated eigenvectors?

Comment: If I remember well, it can happen when the matrix is not diagonalisable; but I don't have any example at hand. Anyway, a complete solution comes from the so-called `invariant factors`, which characterises a class of similarity.

Comment: @Bernard: Still, while not too elegant of an answer, the  matrix I specified does give a counter example. Not quite best-possible answer, but it does provide some information.