# Eigenvalue multiplicity of $n$ by $n$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

If we let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix with an eigenvalue of $1$ with multiplicity $n$, is it accurate to say that $A$ is always diagonalizable?

Comment: Depends on whether you mean geometric multiplicity or algebraic multiplicity.  See this post for some explanations: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324427/how-to-find-the-multiplicity-of-eigenvalues/324437#324437

Comment: I am referring to algebraic

Comment: Then the answer is no.  The matrix with rows [1,1] and [0,1] provides a counterexample.

Comment: If it was geometric multiplicity would it be true?

Comment: @ sawreals2  Yes.

Comment: Interesting as I just had an exam on this question and I wrote it word for word how it was written, there was no mention of if it was geometric or algebraic in the question rhetoric...

Comment: Jordan block of order $n$ (or $2,...,n$).

Comment: By default "multiplicity" can be assumed to refer to algebraic multiplicity

Comment: @sawreals2:  if there was no mention of whether it was geometric or algebraic, the answer is no since the question admits the possibility of the algebraic case.

Comment: @sawreals2:  unless of course Misha Lavrov's comment is correct--but I've never seen that convention; doesn't mean it doesn't exist, however . . .

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ were diagonalizable then your diagonal matrix would be identity matrix $I$ and you would have $A=PIP^{-1} = I$.

So if $A$ is not identity matrix and has $n$   eigenvalues $=1$ then it is not diagonalizable.