# Finding eigen vectors/eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Finding eigen vectors/eigen values of $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 7 & 0 & -3 \\
> -9 & -2 & 3 \\
> 18 & 0 & -8 
> \end{pmatrix}$$

So I understand the eigen values for this matrix are $~1~$&$~2~$, what I don't understand is why should a $~3\times 3~$ matrix have only two eigen values and not $3~$?

Thanks

Comment: Think of the identity matrix $I$. How many eigenvalues does it have?

Comment: You may want to read this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324427/how-to-find-the-multiplicity-of-eigenvalues/324437

Comment: Technically 0 is the only eigenvalue for such a matrix.

Comment: For the same exact reason that the function $-(x-1)(x+2)^2$ is a degree two polynomial but only has 2 distinct roots.

Comment: $2$ is not an eigenvalue of this matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Eigen values are the root 's of a (characteristic) polynomial and polynomial can have repeted roots, like e.g. $p(x) = x^3-3x+2 = (x-1)^2(x+2)$.